# drag to reorder and save state with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a small app that uses the react-sortable-hoc

everything is great but im having issues displaying the list ordered by **order**

I have

```
user 0
user 1
user 2
```

when I drag user 2 above user 0
instead of getting

```
user 2
user 0
user 1
```

I get

```
user 2
user 1
user 0
```

I think It has to do with the way I'm setting the order in the state. but I can't figure it out.

this is how I set the order on sort end

```
const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {

    setUsers(prevState => {
        const newItems = [...prevState];
        newItems[newIndex].order = oldIndex;
        newItems[oldIndex].order = newIndex;
        return newItems.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    })
};
```

here's the app running so you can play with it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-https-xelrd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it, 
here is the working url to play with https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-colden-rm62y

You were correct in guessing that the problem was with the `onSortEnd` function. Instead of swapping the newIndex and oldIndex position we just need to either bubble them up or down.

Here is a working code, it can be cleaned up a bit, but you got the idea :)

```
const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
      const newItems = [...prevState];

      if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
        for (let i = oldIndex - 1; i >= newIndex; i--) {
          newItems[i].order++;
          newItems[oldIndex].order = newIndex;
        }
      } else if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
        for (let i = oldIndex + 1; i <= newIndex; i++) {
          newItems[i].order--;
          newItems[oldIndex].order = newIndex;
        }
      }
      return newItems.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    });
  };
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: I dont understand it but it works. let me get some coffee and read it again :) :)

Comment: Ok :) It is just looping over all the elements and move them one by one either upwards or downwards, and then finally move the dragged element to its new position :)

Comment: nice... I need to console.log only the ones that changed (because I will save to database those) can you help with that please? thank you!

Comment: what you think... const newItems = [...prevState];
   const changed = []
   newItems[oldIndex].order = newIndex;
   changed.push(newItems[oldIndex]);
   if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
    for (let i = oldIndex - 1; i >= newIndex; i--) {
     newItems[i].order++;
     changed.push(newItems[i])
    }
   } else if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
    for (let i = oldIndex + 1; i <= newIndex; i++) {
     newItems[i].order--;
     changed.push(newItems[i])
    }
   }

   console.log(changed)

   return newItems.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  });

Comment: ohh love SO formatting in the comments. sorry about that.

Comment: Horrible to read codes in comments :P Anyway the idea is that, all the items from oldIndex to newIndex (including oldIndex and newIndex) in your items array will be changed.

Comment: cool thanks. wondering if that elseif can be changed with an else. what other case could it be?

Comment: No I guess, because if user drops an item on same position then both the index will be equal, i.e. oldIndex === newIndex will be true. Then we do not need to do anything. actually at the top you can put one check like, if(oldIndex === newIndex) return;

Answer (score 1):

What you do is swapping.

If you want to just "*insert*" the element in the new position you will have to update all the items between the two positions.

In your case, one approach would be to just move the element and re-create the order for all items

```
setUsers(prevState => {
  const newItems = [...prevState];
  newItems.splice(newIndex, 0, newItems.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]).forEach((item,index)=>{
    item.order = index;
  });

  return newItems
});
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-river-mrh3p

Comment: this example doesnt work. im not talking only about new elements. thats "easy" because i just added it to the end of the array (with the order: array.length)

Comment: @handsome the code i posted in my answer works fine, there was an issue with the link i had posted (*it hadn't saved my code*). I have updated the link.

Comment: yeap happened to me before. codesandbox needs an autosave :) so.. you are updating all elements right?

Comment: also I dont see the .order updated I need it because I send everything to the database to persist this stuff

Comment: Inside the `forEach` is where the `order` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like your code is simply swapping the elements. This does not seem like what you really want to do. In fact you really want to remove the element and insert it at a given position. I think since you already have the oldIndex and newIndex, you can approach the sort function as follows:

```
  const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
      var newItems = [...prevState];
      let elem = newItems[oldIndex]
      newItems.splice(oldIndex, 1)
      newItems.splice(newIndex, 0, elem)

     return newItems 
    });
  };
```

There isn't really a need for order and is capturing more than the minimum state required (unless you use it elsewhere).

Comment: yeah order is needed because then I need to save to a dabase so I can persist the state. thanks!

Comment: @handsome there is a point, though, to what @Danny is saying. There is not need to keep the `order` in the UI since you use arrays, and arrays are an ordered type.

Comment: true but I need to save in the database the data in the right order and since I can't remove and add records only to keep the order i need to use an order key. thanks!